# Bubbles and craters in polyurethane

Tags: table, countertops

This is the first time I've done anything like this before. I used a part a and VB a part b type resin. After mixing I applied it to the wood surface. I was told all I had to do is gently blow the bubbles out. Well, that didn't work. The more I blew the more bubbles appeared. So now I let it dry completely and am trying to sand all the bubbles out. My question is, am I supposed to completely sand the entire bubble away, crater and all?? Also, after sanding I cannot completely remove all the dust fom the surface and from inside the craters. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I use a vacuum pot to pull the bubbles out prior to using 2 part, you may need to sand most of the material off and add another coat. Most bubbles especially on a warm day do not disipate and many that have Not worked with 2 part over brush, when I first used 2 part I had the same problem. I sanded it back down then used a cheap vacuum sealer to pull the bubbles out. After that I poured the mix on and was careful not to brush hard and when it starts getting stiff (setting up) left it and I have found this method to be the best. Using mineral spirits with gloves and a rag helps but I could see voids if not totally clean, tough to do.